# Building a cpp project that involves IPP on MSBuild

Tags: c++, msbuild, intel, intel-ipp

I am rather new to cpp and ipp library, I had created a  cpp.sln project which uses Intel IPP (Single-threaded Static Library) and I also able to build the project on Visual Studio.

However now I need to export the project directory to a separate computer and build it there using MSBuild. I am not too sure how do I configure the MSBuild such that it will access the IPP Static library and build the project, can anyone advise on this? Or is there any other files that I need to copy to the separate computer (I had already copy the all the ipp include header files and lib files along with my project files)

Currently when I am trying to build the project on this separate computer (with no IPP installed), I received the following error message

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ippFree referenced in function.....
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ippsMalloc_64_L referenced in function.....
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ippsMalloc_8u referenced in function.....
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ippsZero_64f referenced in function.....
```